# angular ui-keydown is not working with shift+ctrl+alt+A keys

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-ui-utils

For example:

```
<div ui-keydown="'shift-ctrl-alt-65': 'ctrl.scrollFromShortcut($event,\'others\')'"></div>
```

shift-ctrl-65 is working correctly. But shift-ctrl-alt-65 is not working with ui-keydown.
Please help

Comment: Which version of `angular-ui` you're using? Just tried it with `0.4.0` in a `textarea` and it's working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/2pz2jw6v/1/

Comment: angular-ui-utils - Swiss-Army-Knife of AngularJS tools (with no external dependencies!) @version v0.1.1

Comment: Refreshed the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2pz2jw6v/3/ with the version you're using. Still working as expected. What if you try adding `tabindex="1"` to the `div`? If this doesn't work, then I have no clue. I'd check the console, maybe there is an exception there.

Comment: Oh, by the way I just noticed that you are missing the `{ .. }` braces around the attribute value. Try it like this: `ui-keydown="{'shift-ctrl-alt-65': 'ctrl.scrollFromShortcut($event,\'others\')'}"`

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs Dézsi,its working now.after adding {..}

Comment: I'll add it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

So as it turned out you were missing the enclosing `{ ... }` curly braces.

The `ui-keydown` directive expects an object literal where the property name is the key combination and the value is an expression that will be evaluated against the scope.

So the solution is:

```
<div ui-keydown="{'shift-ctrl-alt-65': 'ctrl.scrollFromShortcut($event,\'others\')'}"></div>
```